# Switch statement , only using one case at a time

Tags: java, javafx, switch-statement, javafx-8

Im trying to translate a square 'p' 5 units left or right depending on what key has been pressed . The problem is that when 'right' or 'left' is pressed it will translate 5 units in that direction but when I press again I can't move and I have to press 'left' to move right again so I never get anywhere.
Does anyone know why this is?

```
    Task PlyThread=new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            myScene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    //case UP: p.setTranslateY(((p.getY())-5)) ; break;
                    case LEFT: p.setTranslateX(((p.getX())-5)) ; break;
                    case RIGHT: p.setTranslateX(((p.getX())+5)) ;break;


                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    };new Thread(PlyThread).start();
```

Comment: My guess is that "setTranslateX()" doesn't change whatever "getX()" is returning, so your "getX()" always returns the same value. But I might be wrong, because I have no idea what "p" is.

Comment: P is just a rectangle (20x20)

Comment: The `switch`-statement looks fine to me. I doubt that the bug is within the `switch`. I would either go with @uaraven's theory or suspect that your `event`s have some quirky dependency, not allowing two equal event being fired in succession. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: It is a good idea to add a default case also in your switch statement.

Comment: p.setTranslateX() is the p.setX? I mean are you setting the new value for the same X?

Comment: as I undertsand it 'setTranslateX()' sets the x value to the given value and get(x) returns the x value at the moment in time? So I can continue to move in one direction

Comment: I changed it to:

Comment: setX() and it works? lol

Comment: Why all the redundant parentheses?

Comment: You are using a `Task`, and a separate thread, to simply set the `onKeyPressed` handler. This means you are manipulating a node from a background thread which is a Bad Thing™. Why use a `Task` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I assume that "Rectangle" is `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`. In this case `setTranslateX()` only modifies transformation matrix and does not change the rectangle coordinate X. Value of property X remains unchanged and next call to `setTranslateX(getX()+5)` does exactly the same job as the one before.

You need to work either with translations or with coordinates, i.e. either use  `setTranslateX()`/`getTranslateX()` or `setX()`/`getX()`.

Both choices may have other consequences, beyond moving rectangle on the screen, but I have no experience with JavaFX, so unfortunately I cannot elaborate more.